# Typesetting of the retardation factor (Rf)

Tags: analytical-chemistry, notation, chromatography

What should be the typesetting for the symbol of the [retardation factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retardation_factor) as used in [thin-layer chromatography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-layer_chromatography)?

These are the possibilities:

- R<sub>*f*</sub> - only *f* in italics
- *R<sub>f</sub>* - both *R* and *f* in italics
- *R*<sub>f</sub> - only *R* in italics

On Wikipedia, they have used all sorts of typesetting. There is also *R<sub>F</sub>* with a capital *F*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to *Nomenclature for Chromatography* (IUPAC Recommendations 1993) [1, pp. 843, 845] (also listed in [IUPAC Gold Book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/R/R05353.html)), retardation factor is denoted as follows:

1. Column chromatography: $R$ (capital $R$ in italics).

   > 3.7.13 *Retardation Factor* $(R)$
   >
   > The fraction of the sample component in the mobile phase at equilibrium; it is related to the retention factor and other fundamental chromatography terms:
   >
   > $$R = 1/(k + 1)$$
2. Planar chromatography: $R_\mathrm{F}$ (capital $R$ in italics and upright capital $\mathrm{F}$ in subscript).

   > 3.8.04 *Retardation Factor* ($R_\mathrm{F}$)
   >
   > Ratio of the distance travelled by the center of the spot to the distance simultaneously travelled by the mobile phase. Using the symbols of Fig. 2:
   >
   > $$R_\mathrm{F} = b/a$$
   >
   > By definition the $R_\mathrm{F}$ values are always less than unity. They are usually given to two decimal places.
   > In order to simplify this presentation the $hR_\mathrm{F}$ *Values* may be used: they correspond to the $R_\mathrm{F}$ values multiplied by 100.
   >
   > Ideally, the $R_\mathrm{F}$ values are identical to the $R$ values (see 3.7.13).
   >
   > [image: Fig. 2. Typical planar chromatogram]

#### Reference

1. Ettre, L. S. Nomenclature for Chromatography (IUPAC Recommendations 1993). *Pure Appl. Chem.* **1993**, 65 (4). DOI: [10.1351/pac199365040819](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199365040819).